# Difference between setting in application.properties vs class @Component java spring boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I am learning spring boot. In my application.properties, i set the postgres as such.

```
 jdbc.postgres.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
    jdbc.postgres.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5433/postgres
    jdbc.postgres.username=postgres
    jdbc.postgres.password=password
    jdbc.postgres.pool.name=some-name
```

I have a java class in spring boot with @Configuration. This will help me connect to postgres.

```
@Configuration
@Profile({"dev", "prod"})
public class PostgresConfig {

    @Value(value = "${jdbc.postgres.driver}")
    private String driverName;

    @Value(value = "${jdbc.postgres.url}")
    private String postgresqlUrl;

    @Value(value = "${jdbc.postgres.username}")
    private String postgresqlUserName;

    @Value(value = "${jdbc.postgres.password}")
    private String postgresqlPassword;

    @Value(value = "${jdbc.postgres.pool.name}")
    private String poolName;

    @Bean(name = "postgresDataSource")
    public HikariDataSource postgresDataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(driverName);
        config.setJdbcUrl(postgresqlUrl);
        config.setUsername(postgresqlUserName);
        config.setPassword(postgresqlPassword);
        config.setPoolName(poolName);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");

        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);

        return ds;
    }
}
```

In spring-boot, i can also just set directly in the application.properties to connect to postgres instead of creating a class and annotate with @Component.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5433/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Can i know what is the difference between creating a connection to postgres between this 2 ways? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on which **spring-boot** version you are using:

- **spring-boot 2** : uses `HikariCP` as the default connection pool.

If you want to customize the connection configuration (i.e. connectionTimeout, maximumPoolSize etc..), you can do that programmatically using a bean (as you've done in the first solution) or you can simply do that as properties:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000 
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000 
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000
```

If you just define the **Postgresql** connection details, **spring-boot** will use the default value for the others.

- **spring-boot 1** : uses the `tomcat JDBC connection pool`.

Hence, your first solution will override the default connection pool and you will use `HicariCP` in stead. Whereas, your second solution will keep using the default pool connection.

Comment: Hi, i understand that in the 2 solutions, i can set the hikari values accordingly. May I know what is the difference between setting it in property files vs doing it in class config? (eg is there something to do with spring context with 1 way vs the other?) Or is there no difference? just 2 different ways?

Comment: If you want to define multiple connection pool stratagies (tomcat pool connection stratagy and HicariCP stratagy) or (HicariCP stratagy with x maxPoolConnection and another HicariCP stratagy with y maxPoolConnection), then you need to do that programmatically rather then using separate configuration files and profiles (prodHCP1, prodHCP2 etc). If you are in simple case where you have a mapping one-to-one between properties and values with no rule, then use simply the properties file. Good luck

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, may i see an example of tomcat pool connection program code as shown in the first solution which i posted? i can't seem to find it online. thank u